# How to load Vue.js using Require.js

Tags: vue.js, requirejs

I am using `Angularjs` in my application and I'm trying to create a page inside using `Vue.js`.
For that, I installed Vue using bower and called it's directory inside my require.js file, like this:

```
'vue': '../vendor/vue/dist/vue'

shim: {
  'vue': {
    deps: ['jquery']
  },
}
```

After that I have dashboard.js that is a base/parent file, where I call angular and vue (among others)

```
require([
  'angular',
  'vue',
  'i18next',
  'translations',
  'raven-js',
  'raven-angular',

], function (angular, Vue, i18next, Translations, Raven) {
  'use strict';
```

Finally I've got my `index.html.twig` where I'm using Vue, but I got an error telling me `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined` even tho that vue.js inside vendor is showing with the other scripts when inspecting the page.
I also have this inside that twig:

```
<script>
  var ProjectController = new Vue({
    el: '#ProjectController',
    data: {
      projects: null
    },
    methods:{
     getProjects: function(){
         fetch('/projects/personal').then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
         }).then(function (result) {
            this.projects =  result;
         });
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.getProjects();
    }
  })
</script>
```

I'm guessing it's not the right way to load it (?)

Comment: Are the other packages you require not available as well or is it only Vue?

Comment: @JeBokE The others are working fine, it's just Vue

Comment: @RicardoPimenta Were you able to work around this? I'm facing a similar issue and I'm baffled.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla Not really, sorry; I left this project in standby, but if you find a way, I'd really appreciate if you left an answer. :)