# Why does Vue not initialize when loaded via a script-loader?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic-script-loading

I need to load VueJS dynamically using a script loader but I'm unable to understand why Vue doesn't initialize.

Here's my simple script-loader:

```
(function( w ){
    var loadJS = function( src, cb ){
        "use strict";
        var ref = w.document.getElementsByTagName( "script" )[ 0 ];
        var script = w.document.createElement( "script" );
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore( script, ref );
        if (cb && typeof(cb) === "function") {
            script.onload = cb;
        }
        return script;
    };
    // commonjs
    if( typeof module !== "undefined" ){
        module.exports = loadJS;
    }
    else {
        w.loadJS = loadJS;
    }
}( typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : this ));
```

In the browser console, I invoke the script-loader using this:

```
loadJS('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js')
```

I can see VueJS being requested in the network panel, but typing `Vue` into the console gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined` error.

I'm able to load other libs using the same script loader but not Vue. I'm baffled.

Comment: Why don't you use a robust loader like SystemJS or RequireJS instead of rolling your own?

Comment: I guess I could but that seems to have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396625/how-to-load-vue-js-using-require-js

Comment: Without seeing how you use `Vue` in your app, it's tough to say. I imagine something like this would at least work though `SystemJS.import("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js").then(({default: Vue}) => window.Vue = Vue);`

Comment: Alternately with RequireJS: `require(["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"], Vue => window.Vue = Vue);`

Comment: You're doing `script.async = true;`. How are you including the script that consumes `Vue`? I suspect you're not loading that asynchronously as well, so it gets  executed before `Vue` is available. The other cause might be that loading `Vue` as a module won't automatically expose a global `Vue` variable.

Comment: Removing `script.async = true;` has the same effect. I'm simply running in this the browser console. The snippet above was supposed to be SSCCE. `require(["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"], Vue => window.Vue = Vue);` seems to work which is even more confusing as to why Vue won't load in my simple example.

Comment: Probably because you have some environmental factor that is causing Vue to assume an AMD environment. One example of this that is known to occur is if you use ESRI AGO maps. Many ESRI libs at least prior to v4 bundle an AMD loader and left its global `define` and `require` functions defined afterwards. UMD distributions loaded by script tags further on would then not provide their globals because they detected an AMD environment. In any case, if you didn't add RequireJS to your project and that call worked, it means you have it or some other loader available and you should use it. Globals suck